# New comment indent spacing inconsistency

Tags: bug, comments

Well, I'm unsure if this is a bug or not, though I've tagged it as such anyway.  To the point, there appears to be a bit of an inconsistency in the spacing of a newly-created comment, which is then fixed by refresh.

I just noticed this today, and haven't been able to find any similar questions concerning the matter, so if this is a duplicate, I apologize.

To the report.. Upon submitting a new comment, a td is created which is empty, making the comment float to the left.  Upon refresh, that td is filled with the comment vote information(the table, classes, etc).  This is reproducable.. at least on my end.  In order to do so, the comment must be made on a question that has no comments on it already.  Refresh to see the change.  As to what it looks like..

[image: Empty TD spacing on new comment creation, before refresh]
[image: Full TD spacing on new comment creation, after refresh]

So as to the question.. I guess I'm wondering if this is the intended behavior?

Comment: I've been seeing this as well, it makes me feel slightly strange whenever it happens; the expectation that something has changed but nothing has